# Running python script from html from nodejs

Tags: python, php, html, node.js

Bare with me, i have a pretty complex setting here (i'd be happy to get it simpler)
I have a nodejs server running (for localhost access) the nodejs is reading a file and output in browser

This gives me the possibility to have my own server for testing multiple things so i can access localhost/test.html or localhost/web.php for example. and it works fine.

Now i want to control lights. i have a python script that can do that (and it works very well in terminal)

Now i want to be able to run the script using a simple button on the html page ran by nodejs.

I've tried multiple things, including pythonshell, php, but can't find the working one..

So I can i run a python script from my page outputed in browser by nodejs ?

EDIT :

here is in more detail how evreything is running :
I node a **app.js** running a simple read file and get url

app.js

```
http = require("http"),
path = require("path"),
url = require("url"),
fs = require("fs");

function sendError(errCode, errString, response)
{
  response.writeHead(errCode, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write(errString + "\n");
  response.end();
  return;
}

function sendFile(err, file, response)
{
  if(err) return sendError(500, err, response);
  response.writeHead(200);
  response.write(file, "binary");
  response.end();
}

function getFile(exists, response, localpath)
{
  if(!exists) return sendError(404, '404 Not Found', response);
  fs.readFile(localpath, "binary",
   function(err, file){ sendFile(err, file, response);});
}

function getFilename(request, response)
{
  var urlpath = url.parse(request.url).pathname; // following domain or IP and port
  var localpath = path.join(process.cwd(), urlpath); // if we are at root
  fs.exists(localpath, function(result) { getFile(result, response, localpath)});
}

var server = http.createServer(getFilename);
server.listen(1000);
console.log("Server available...");
```

from there i can call any files in the same dir, i therefore call a **index.html**

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>
  <body class="text-white bg-dark">
    <center>
    <form method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="OFF" name="OFF" onclick="turnOff()">
    <input type="submit" value="ON" name="ON" onclick="turnOn()">
    </form>
    </center>
    
    <script>
    function turnOff(){
        //something i need to call shell command python3 turnOff.py
    }

    function turnOn(){
        //something i need to call shell command python3 turnOn.py
    }
    
    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

And i have two files **turnOn.py** and **turnOff.py**

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried writing the output of the script into a file, and displaying the file contents in the browser?

Comment: I have a .py file in the same root, i just can’t find how to run it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is the same server, you can run code in the following way

```
   exec('python code.py');
```

see: https://medium.com/stackfame/how-to-run-shell-script-file-or-command-using-nodejs-b9f2455cb6b7

Comment: that is a working idea :) But since i'd like to run the script from a button in html page, i can't require child_process to run exec..

Comment: The idea is - when you click on an HTML button, you will send a request (for example ajax) to your nodeJS server to run this code

Comment: thanks, i just don't know anything about ajax request, could you tell me an exemple on how to use it ?

Comment: Please mark this question as resolved and open new one with a specific question in the way you need help.  see:
[AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp), [jQueryAjax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)